# Exercise6-4 programming in c

Tags: c

Right now I am learning to program in c by reading the book "Programming in C, 3rd edition" by Stephen Kockan.
Exercise6-4 in the book is really giving me a headache. In the book it says:

```
Write a program that acts as a simple "printing" calculator. 

The program should allow the user to type in expressions of the form
```

***number operator***

The following operatros should be recognized by the program:

```
 '+'  '-'  '*'  '/'  'S'  'E'
```

The S operator tells the program to set the "accumulator" to the
 typed-in number. The E operator tells the program that execution is to
 end. The arithmetic operations are performed on the content of the
 accumulator with the number that was keyed in acting as the seconcd
 operand.

[Here is a link](http://classroomm.com/objective-c/index.php?action=printpage;topic=377.0),to how i figured it out too.

Unfortunately it's in Objective-C(but is still the same exercise!), and I don't understand
 Objective-C syntax.

UPDATE

This is what I have made so far:

```
// "Printing" Calculator

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char  operator;
    float value, result, accumulator;

    printf("Begin Calculations...\n\n");

    operator = '0';

    while ( operator != 'E')
    {
        scanf("%f %c", &value, &operator);
        switch(operator)
        {
            case 'S':
                accumulator = value;
                printf("The accumulator = %f", accumulator);
                break;
            case '+':
                result = accumulator + value;
                printf("%f + %f = %f", accumulator, value, result);
                break;
            case '-':
                break;
            case '*':
                break;
            case '/':
                break;
            default:
                printf("Unknown operator");
                break;
        }
    }

    printf("Calculations terminated");

    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out how to use the `scanf()` function, and read both a value for an operation and a value for the accumulator. Because those two thing may not be the same.

Comment: And your question is?...

Comment: Sorry, what's the problem?

Comment: Are you expecting an Objective C to pure C conversion ?

Comment: declare a variable `char` and then using `switch` recognize the operator; wait a minute, am I answering this question?

Comment: I'm really sorry, understand your frustration. My question is, how can you write this in C?

Comment: I've edited your sample program so that it actually compiles, but otherwise, it appears it does what you want: the `scanf()` statement is fine as it is now (though it will fail when you enter bad input, uch as a non-number for the value).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your C code.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h>

int main (void) 
{ 
    int loop; 
    float value, 
    acc = 0; 
    char o;
    printf ("Simple Printing Calculator Program\n\n"); 
    printf ("\nKEY: \n+ Add \n- Subtract \n* Multiply \n/ Divide\n"); 
    printf ("S Set Accumulator \nE End Program\n\n"); 
    printf ("Enter a number and an operator, then press enter\n\n"); 
    printf ("Type in your expression: ");
    for ( loop=0 ; loop>-1; ++loop)
    {
        {
        scanf ("%f %c", &value, &o);
        if ( o == '+' )
        { 
            acc = acc + value; printf ("\n%.2f\n",acc); 
        }
        else if ( o == '-' )
        { 
            acc = acc - value; printf ("\n%.2f\n",acc); 
        }
        else if ( o == '*' )
        { 
            acc = acc * value; printf ("\n%.2f\n",acc); 
        }
        else if ( o == 'S' )
        { 
            acc = value; printf ("\n%.2f\n",acc); 
        }
        else if ( o == 'E' )
        { 
            printf ("\nFinal Value: %.2f\n\nGoodbye!",acc); loop = loop + 1000; 
        }
        else if ( o == '/' ) 
            if ( value == 0 )
            { 
                loop = loop - loop -100; 
                printf ("\nDivision by zero.\n"); 
            } 
            else
            { 
                acc = acc / value; printf ("\n%.2f\n", acc); 
            } 
        else
        { 
            loop = loop -loop-100; 
            printf ("\nUnknown operator.\n"); 
        }
    }
    getch (); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: why should that terminate after 1000 expressions? The declaration of sum is obscure to the point of confusion, and there's no indenting.

Comment: that stops after one pass, and the declaration of sum is still confusing.

Comment: why use a loop counter? why not just break out of it?

Comment: for (<optional initialiser statement>; <optional termination condition>; <optional statement>)